# Microsoft Excel _how to expand values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I have got 2 columns. Column A has got Identities in it, and column B has got a quantity, I want to expand this so that it results in a column with just the identities in it repeated as many times as the quantity.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Put the formula `REPT(A1,B1)` in cell C1 and fill down as far as you need.

`REPT` repeats a piece of text multiple times. For example, `REPT("ABC", 3)` returns "ABCABCABC".